# circular override in bash

Tags: bash, http, curl, awk, line-endings

What is going on here?

```
content=$(curl -s http://localhost:3000 -I | grep -Fi Content-Type | awk '{print $2}')
echo "${content}1234"
```

res:

```
1234ication/x-protobuf
```

the `curl -I` response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 10013
Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2018 18:00:06 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

as you can see, the webserver is a normal express app, no middlewares, all boilerplate, nothing special

further more, checking

```
if [ "$content" == "application/x-protobuf" ]
```

is always false (I've tried other variations of the condition as well)

1. What is the circular override business
2. why isn't content what is printed on the screen?

Comment: Use `echo $content | cat -v` to see the hidden characters in your string.

Comment: `application/x-protobuf^M` where did that come from??

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings, which results in the value of `content` ending with a carriage return.

Comment: this is typed in terminal on a mac in bash :/

Comment: line endings from network protocols are typically CRLF. You could try `awk '{sub(/\r$/,""); print $2}'`

Comment: The HTTP protocol spec (RFC2616) says that headers are terminated with CRLF. Curl is only dumping what it's getting from the server.

Comment: Another easy way to strip those chars: `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: BTW, not your issue (which was already described above), but `[ foo == foo ]` isn't guaranteed to be true in POSIX shells on its own, because `==` isn't a POSIX-defined string comparison operator. Use `=` to be robust and portable.